# How to add flutter tags from api on click?

Tags: flutter

In this below image, it is divided into 2 parts:

1. Textfield to create tags
2. Some data fetched from api and shown in grid view

Both are working fine but what I need is when I click on any of the boxes in grid view I want that same data to apper in above textfield.

I am using a package called **textfield_tags** for creating tags (textfield)

```
TextFieldTags(
  textfieldTagsController: _controller,
  initialTags: _skillsLists,
  textSeparators: const [' ', ','],
  letterCase: LetterCase.normal,
  validator: (String tag) {
  if (tag.length < 3) {
    return 'Tag cannot be smaller than 3 characters';
  } else if (_controller.getTags!.contains(tag)) {
    return 'Tag already exists';
  }
},
```

The above is code for the textfield tags, and there is a field named initialTags in above code and there is a list called **_skillsLists** which is initialized at top like this:

```
 List<String> _skillsLists = ['Figma'];
```

and in my below line I have created a grid view where if any of those boxes are clicked the data of the boxes are added to the list.

**For example if I click on HTML from girdview it is added to the list but it doesn't appear in above textfield as tags, it is just added to the list. What should I do? setState doen't help here.** I also tried using addTag which is a function of TextFieldTags but is throws error saying **'The method 'addTag' isn't defined for the type 'TextfieldTagsController'.'**

```
GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: _data.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Containers(
        onTap: () {
          controller.addTag(_data[index].name); // this line show 
          error
          setState(() {
            _skillsLists.add(_data[index].name);

          });
          print(_skillsLists);
        },
        width: size.width,
        color: Colors.pink,
        height: 30,
        child: Texts(texts: _data[index].name),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

[image: img]

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, addTag is a setter. You will have to write it like `controller..addTag = _data[index].name`. The `..` would be necessary.